# VS Code: Add single file (README) to multi-root workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

You can configure a vs-code [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) to include several folders. Eg,

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      // Source code
      "name": "Product",
      "path": "vscode"
    },
    {
      // Docs and release notes
      "name": "Documentation",
      "path": "vscode-docs"
    },
    {
      // Yeoman extension generator
      "name": "Extension generator",
      "path": "vscode-generator-code"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would also like to include a README file from a root directory that pertains to all those folders. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: No, with multi-root workspaces there is no "above" root location. If you need this, how about using a normal workspace with a single root folder and adding symlinks to all your project folders inside?

Comment: There is long standing feature [request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45177)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't supported in Visual Studio Code. There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/45177) that's been open for this feature since 2018.

Comment: Really, really, **really** sad that this is still an issue in 2023.

Answer (score 0):

As a very non-user-friendly option, but if you really need it, you can add the root directory (File > Add Folder to Workspace). Then in configuration file, exclude files you don't want; see example below.

```
"settings": {
        "files.exclude": {
            "**/*Backup": true,
            "**/*.sln": true,
            "**/.hg": true,
            "**/CVS": true,
            "**/.DS_Store": true,
            "**/Thumbs.db": true
        }
}
```